# Remove Rows Based on User-Input Conditions (Pandas,Python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Say I have a DF like this

```
  Words1            Score     
 The Man                 10        
 Right Hand              7         
 Bad Boy Company         7  
 Seven Deadly Sins       11
```

What I was hoping to do was create a user input like this:

```
var = input("Enter the Words That Can Never Appear Together in the same phrase: ")
```

Where the user enters words that should never appear together in a phrase.  So lets say that var = Bad Company' the DF becomes after df.dropna()

```
  Words1           Score     
 The Man             10        
 Right Hand           7   
 Seven Deadly Sins   11
```

**So I have two questions**: Is there any way to actually do this?  And if so, if there a way to support multiple queries, such as if someone wanted a row removed that contained an instance where 'Bad' and 'Company' appeared in phrase and also any rows removed where  'Seven' and 'Sins' appears in a phrase?

Hopefully someone can help me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can vectorize 'Words1' into a series and then apply a regex:

```
>>> df
   Score              Words
0     10            The Man
1      7         Right Hand
2      7    Bad Boy Company
3     11  Seven Deadly Sins
>>> df['Words'].str.contains('Bad')
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
Name: Words, dtype: bool
>>> df['Words'].str.contains('^(?=.*Bad)(?=.*Company)')
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
Name: Words, dtype: bool
```

Then use those booleans to remove the one you do not want with boolean masking:

```
>>> df=df[df['Words'].str.contains('^(?=.*Bad)(?=.*Company)')==False]
>>> df
   Score              Words
0     10            The Man
1      7         Right Hand
3     11  Seven Deadly Sins

[3 rows x 2 columns]
>>> df=df[df['Words'].str.contains('^(?=.*Sins)(?=.*Seven)')==False]
>>> df
   Score       Words
0     10     The Man
1      7  Right Hand

[2 rows x 2 columns]
```

---

To split user input into patterns:

```
>>> s=raw_input('Words: ')
Words: Seven Sins
>>> s
'Seven Sins'
>>> pattern='^'+''.join('(?=.*{})'.format(word) for word in s.split())
>>> pattern
'^(?=.*Seven)(?=.*Sins)'
```

Comment: This is a very nifty solution, thank you dawg :).  However, is there a way to adapt this so that the words used within the regex can be user inputted?